# Can't get velocity right in the range-doppler map of a received signal from 1 target

Tags: fft, matlab, doppler

I have written a code that simulates a target at 400 m and velocity of 100 m/s.
I calculated tau_t the time delay due the the range and the velocity, then I created a received signal from the transmitted signal with samples corresponding to the delay, as you can see.
then I produced the doppler range map by match filtering each PRI with the transmitted pulse and then applying a FFT over the matrix columns. The map shows me the correct range but velocity 0 in oppose to 100.
can anyone locate the error?

I know that most of the time you can artificially add the doppler frequency to the signal but I thought I could get it naturally from the time delay.

```
% Parameters
PRI = 5e-6;      % Pulse Repetition Interval in seconds
Pw = 2e-6;       % Pulse Width in seconds
CPI = 0.5e-3;    % Coherent Processing Interval in seconds
B = 100e6;       % Bandwidth in Hz
fc = 40e9;       % Carrier Frequency in Hz
fs = 2 * B;      % Sampling frequency, at least twice the bandwidth (Nyquist rate)

N = CPI / PRI;

t_Pw = -Pw/2:1/fs:Pw/2-1/fs;
t_CPI = 0:1/fs:CPI-1/fs;
h_t = exp((1j*pi*B/Pw)*(t_Pw).^2);
S_TX_t = zeros(1, length(t_CPI));


for n = 0:N-1
    t_pulse = n * PRI + Pw/2 + t_Pw;
    indices = floor(n * PRI * fs) + (1:length(t_Pw));
    S_TX_t(indices) = h_t .* exp(1j * 2 * pi * fc * t_pulse);
end

%{
% Plot the real part of the pulse
figure;
plot(t_Pw, real(h_t));
title('Real Part of the LFM Pulse');
xlabel('Time (seconds)');
ylabel('Amplitude');

% Plot the imaginary part of the pulse
figure;
plot(t_Pw, imag(h_t));
title('Imaginary Part of the LFM Pulse');
xlabel('Time (seconds)');
ylabel('Amplitude');

% Plot the magnitude of the pulse
figure;
plot(t_Pw, abs(h_t));
title('Magnitude of the LFM Pulse');
xlabel('Time (seconds)');
ylabel('Amplitude');

% Plot the phase of the pulse
figure;
plot(t_Pw, angle(h_t));
title('Phase of the LFM Pulse');
xlabel('Time (seconds)');
ylabel('Phase (radians)');

% Calculate the FFT of the pulse
H_f = fft(h_t);

% Calculate the frequency vector
f = (-length(t_Pw)/2:length(t_Pw)/2-1)*(fs/length(t_Pw));

% Plot the frequency domain representation
figure;
plot(f, fftshift(abs(H_f)));
title('Frequency Domain Representation of the LFM Pulse');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Magnitude');

% Calculate the autocorrelation of the pulse
[R_hh, lags] = xcorr(h_t, 'biased');

% Time vector for the autocorrelation
t_ac = lags / fs;

% Plot the autocorrelation
figure;
plot(t_ac, abs(R_hh));
title('Autocorrelation of the LFM Pulse');
xlabel('Lag (seconds)');
ylabel('Autocorrelation Magnitude');

% Plot the real part of the transmit signal
plot(t_CPI, real(S_TX_t));
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('Real Part of Transmit Signal S_{TX}(t)');
grid on;
%}

%%%

% 1 target recived signal
R_0 = 400; % distance in meters
v = 330; % velocity in meters per sec
sigma = 1;
c = 3e8; % Speed of light in meters/second

R_t = R_0 + v * t_CPI;
tau_t = 2 * R_t / c;
% Initialize the received signal
S_RX_t = zeros(1, length(t_CPI));

% Time vector for the transmitted signal


% Loop over each point in the CPI time vector
for idx = 1:length(t_CPI)
    % Calculate the time point in the transmitted signal after applying the delay
    delayed_time = t_CPI(idx) - tau_t(idx);

    % Check if the delayed time is within the bounds of the transmitted signal
    if delayed_time >= 0 && delayed_time <= t_CPI(end)
        % Use interpolation to find the signal value at the non-integer delay time
        S_RX_t(idx) = interp1(t_CPI, S_TX_t, delayed_time, 'linear', 0);
    end
end

figure;
plot(t_CPI  , real(S_RX_t));
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('Real Part of Received Signal S_{RX}(t) with Time-Varying Range');
grid on;

%BaseBand recieved signal
S_RX_t_BB = S_RX_t.* exp(-1j * 2 * pi * fc * t_CPI);


%%%

% orgenize the PRI in am matrix

samples_in_pulse = round(Pw * fs);
samples_per_PRI = round(PRI * fs);
samples_in_received_part = samples_per_PRI - samples_in_pulse;
received_parts_matrix = zeros(N, samples_in_received_part);

for i = 1:N
    current_PRI_start = (i - 1) * samples_per_PRI + samples_in_pulse +1;
    current_PRI_end = current_PRI_start + samples_in_received_part - 1;
    received_parts_matrix(i, :) = S_RX_t_BB(current_PRI_start:current_PRI_end);
end


% Assuming h_t is your transmitted signal pulse
% First, create the matched filter coefficients, which is the time-reversed complex conjugate of h_t
matched_filter_coefficients = conj(fliplr(h_t));


% Initialize a matrix to store the matched filtering output
matched_filter_output = zeros(size(received_parts_matrix)+size(h_t)-1);

% Apply the matched filter to each received signal part (each row of the matrix)
for i = 1:size(received_parts_matrix, 1)
    % Perform matched filtering using convolution and keep the result
    % in 'same' size to match the input signal size
    matched_filter_output(i, :) = conv(received_parts_matrix(i, :), ...
                                       matched_filter_coefficients);
end

% FFT to each column

fft_points = size(matched_filter_output, 1);
fft_matrix = zeros(fft_points, size(matched_filter_output, 2));

for col = 1:size(matched_filter_output, 2)
    fft_matrix(:, col) = fft(matched_filter_output(:, col), fft_points);
end





Fs = 1/PRI; % Sampling frequency (Hz)

doppler_bin_width = Fs/N; % Frequency for each bin (Hz)
doppler_bins = (0:N-1) * doppler_bin_width; % Doppler frequency bins (Hz)
% Shift the Doppler bins so that zero frequency is in the center
doppler_bins = fftshift(doppler_bins);
doppler_bins(doppler_bins >= Fs/2) = doppler_bins(doppler_bins >= Fs/2) - Fs;


% Shift the FFT results for proper visualization
fft_matrix_shifted = fftshift(fft_matrix, 1);

% Calculate the magnitude of the FFT results
fft_magnitude = abs(fft_matrix_shifted);

% Range bins (assuming each column in correlation_matrix corresponds to a range bin)
range_bins = (1:size(matched_filter_output, 2))*c/(2*fs);

% Plotting the Doppler map
figure;
imagesc(range_bins, doppler_bins, 10*log10(fft_magnitude));
xlabel('Range Bin');
ylabel('Doppler Frequency (Hz)');
title('Range-Doppler Map');
colorbar;
axis xy;

% Constants
c = 3e8; % Speed of light in meters/second

% Wavelength of the radar signal
lambda = c / fc;

% Calculate velocities corresponding to the Doppler frequency shifts
% Negative sign accounts for the convention that positive frequency shift is for targets moving away
velocities = doppler_bins * lambda / 2;

% Plotting the velocity-range map
figure;
imagesc(range_bins, velocities, 10*log10(fft_magnitude));
xlabel('Range Bin');
ylabel('Velocity (m/s)');
title('Velocity-Range Map');
colorbar;
axis xy;
```